# Ignoring duplicate records on query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below,

```
cid  uid  aid  gid  NAME  evn

1     1    1     1   aa   aa
1     1    1     2   bb   aa
1     1    2     2   bb   bb
1     2    1     1   aa   aa
2     1    1     1   aa   aa
2     1    1     1   aa   aa
2     2    2     2   bb   bb
2     2    2     2   aa   bb
3     3    2     2   aa   bb
3     3    2     2   aa   bb
```

but I want query output should be look like

```
cid  uid  aid  gid  NAME  evn 
 1    1    1     1   aa   aa
 1    2    1     1   aa   aa
 2    1    1     1   aa   aa
 2    2    2     2   bb   bb
 3    3    2     2   aa   bb
```

In my input table,I have cid,uid combination like (1,1),(1,1)(1,1) repeating, but in my output query result should be (1,1).i.e, one time.
I am not bothering about other columns.I have tried groupBy  but it is not working as expected.

Comment: It's either mysql or sql-server, my friend.

Comment: Why such a tag spam? What exactly DBMS (from three different you've mentioned in tags) are you using?

Comment: I removed the extraneous tags.  Add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about other columns, then just use aggregation:

```
select cid, uid, min(aid), min(gid), min(name), min(evn)
from t
group by cid, uid;
```

This pulls "arbitrary" values from the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT` keyword like this :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT cid, uid, aid, gid, name, evn FROM ....
```